# django multi user request(a,b concurrent request)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I make django rest api. ( window server )
this api receive json data from user.
and return json data for request user.

I test A and B two user same time request. 
A receive B result data and B can not receive any data.

how to solve please help me

```
@csrf_exempt    
def ex(request, question_id):
        received_json_data = json.loads(request.body.decode("utf-8"))
        sys.argv = ["getdata", received_json_data['url']]  
        returnData = main()
        return JsonResponse(json.loads(returnData), safe=False)
```

Comment: Where does `returnData` come from?

Comment: sorry late answer, I use console program. view ex function call console program and return data